# awk print variable value

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to print the variable value defined outside **awk** snippet.

**Code Snippet**

```html
FailCounter=5

awk -v Fail=${FailCounter} -F, ' BEGIN {
        print "<TABLE border=1>"
        print "<TR><TD colspan=2> &nbsp;</font></TD></TR>"
} NR == 1 {
        print "<TR><TH colspan=2 bgcolor=\\#FECACA><font face=verdana size=3 color=black>Failed Status Summary</font></TH></TR>"
        print "<TR><TH bgcolor=\\#B7B1B1><font face=verdana size=3 color=black>" $1 "</font></TH>"
        print "<TH bgcolor=\\#B7B1B1><font face=verdana size=3 color=black>" $2 "</font></TH></TR>"
} NR > 1 {
        print "<TR><TD><font face=verdana size=3>" $1 "</font></TD>"
        print "<TD><font face=verdana size=3>" $2 "</font></TD></TR>"
} END {
        print "<TR><TD>Total</TD><TD>${FAIL}</TD></TR>"
        print "</TABLE>"
} ' ${ScanOutage} >> ${OutputFile}
```

The `FailCounter` variable is defined outside the awk block, I am unable to write `-v Fail=${FailCounter}` value in the `END` section of the awk script. It simply prints as is.

Please help me with this issue.

**Current output**

```
<TR><TD>Total</TD><TD>${FAIL}</TD></TR>
```

**Intended output**

```
<TR><TD>Total</TD><TD>5</TD></TR>
```

Answer (score 4):

In `awk`, `$foo` does not mean "the value of the variable named `foo`", it means "the field whose number is the value of the variable `foo`". If you want to refer to a variable, you don't use `$`. For example:

```
$ echo "aa bb cc" | awk -v field=3 '{ print "field number",field, "is:",$field }'
field number 3 is: cc
```

So in your case, in order to print out the value of the awk variable `Fail` which you define on the command line, you need to `print Fail` and not `$Fail` and certainly not `${FAIL}` since you don't have any variable called `FAIL` (things are case sensitive). So you are probably looking for something like this:

```
END{
   print "<TR><TD>Total</TD><TD>"Fail"</TD></TR>"
   print "</TABLE>"
}
```

Note how I need to close the quotes, then use the variable name, and then open new quotes.

Comment: Thank you @terdon. That worked.

Comment: You're welcome, @VCPMuthukrishna. If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.